# ASP other value are come out but only textarea is not come out

Tags: html, asp.net

comarea is not showing i already tried **<%=comarea%>**
others are all shoing like **<%=comid%>** or **<%=compwd%>**
i think it's related about sql data form
comdid and compwd is varchar in sql only comarea is text data form
should i change comarea data form?

```
<%
    Option explicit
    Dim comseq,intseq,comid,compwd,comarea,dtm_date
    Dim objrs,objdbconn,dsntest
    Dim comsql
    Dim intnowpage,intpagesize,ascdesc

    intseq=request.querystring("seq")
    comseq=request.querystring("comseq")

    Set objdbconn=server.createobject("adodb.connection")
    Set objrs=server.createobject("adodb.recordset")

    dsntest=""

    objdbconn.open dsntest

    comsql="select comid,compwd,comarea from comment where intseq =" &intseq
    comsql=comsql & " and comseq = " &comseq

    objrs.open comsql,objdbconn

    comid=objrs(0)
    compwd=objrs(1)
    comarea=objrs(2) 



%>
      <!-- #include virtual="remake/SideBar.asp" -->

    <div class="card">
        <form method="post" name="comform" action="content_ok.asp?seq=<%=intseq%>">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<%=objrs(0)%>" name="comid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<%=objrs(1)%>" name="compwd">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" class="form-control" name="comarea"><%=objrs(2)%></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()?seq=<%=intseq%>">저장</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- #include virtual="remake/Script.asp" -->

[enter image description here][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTR6J.png
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning a valid value for the comarea assignment?

Comment: Thanks i changed comarea --> <%=strContent%> 
then working